# How to hide part of the email on the printout in MS Outlook - blank pages

Tags: html, css, printing, outlook, html-email

I need to print out an email from desktop Outlook (Office 365) BUT with some hidden sections (meaningless headers and footers) so that the most important content fits into one page.

I added `@media print` and `display: none` CSS style which did the trick, however, desktop Outlook incorrectly calculates document height, as if those hidden sections were still visible.
Because of that, an extra blank page is printed. I need to somehow fix that. Maybe someone already faced this problem and has a workaround.

I've prepared a simplified HTML email body which depicts the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  @media print {
      .not-printable {
        display: none;
      }
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  start
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 400px;">This div should be visible both on screen and in printout.</div>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; height: 400px;" class="not-printable">This div should be visible on screen only</div>
  end
</body>
</html>
```

[image: print preview]

I am aware that:

- the beast would be to completely remove headers and footers
- nothing is guaranteed when it comes to displaying and printing emails
- some workaround could be to generate a PDF file and attach it to the email
- desktop MS Office is using Word as a rendering engine which sucks

Unfortunately, due to business requirements, those are not the options.

Comment: From what I can see on the picture, the second div is hidden on PrintPreview. The vertical empty distance comes from `height: 400px;` which is applied to the first div. is that the situation?

Comment: yes, the second DIV is hidden as excepted but its height is still "added" to the total document height, thus two pages. Yes, the vertical empty space between "this div should ..." and "end" is because of `height: 400px`. I've added it to simulate situation when it has more content. The blank page doesn't go off if I remove that inline style and put actual content (lorem ipsum etc).

Comment: Okay then. What if you try to add `display: none!important` to the class?

Comment: yes, this was one of the things I've tried at the very begging. Needless to say, it didn't help.

Comment: I have had some very negative experience with Outlook. If it's possible to have a look at the email code inside  Outlook, you might find something.

Comment: can you add a style to not-printable, e.g. `height: 0 !important;`?